# CUDA Stream Scheduling

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am working on a code in C++ using CUDA to execute the same task with 5 streams. The sequence of operations in one stream is Memcpy - cudaMemcpy (Host to Device) - Kernel - cudaMemcpy (Device to Host) - Memcpy. However, I am facing an issue where the cudaMemcpy (Device to Host) needs to be completed before proceeding with memcpy.

Is there a way to ensure that memcpy is executed only after cudaMemcpy (Device to Host) has completed, without waiting for all streams to finish using cudaStreamSynchronize? I want to pause only one stream while maintaining asynchrony with other streams.

Comment: Use events. Record it in one stream, [synchronize the other on it](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#explicit-synchronization). Relevant blog post: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/

Comment: You can launch the host memcpy into the same CUDA stream using cudaLaunchHostFunc

Comment: I've tried almost everything there, but the issue persists. Asynchronous execution seems to work, but at the point of Stream synchronization, it appears as if the GPU is waiting for all Streams to complete. Should each Stream exist in a different thread?

Comment: Or Could synchronization vary depending on the specifications of the GPU?

I'm really curious.

Comment: I just resolved it using a callback function and cudaLaunchHostFunc! Thank you very much

Comment: @KKang: Please add your solution as an answer to the question so that it is available to the next person who has a similar issue

Comment: If you synchronize a single host thread with each stream, all streams are synchronized with each other at that point, too. However, `cudaLaunchHostFunc` is the best solution in your case.

Comment: I highly recommend you run [Nvidia's Nsight Systems](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems) on your program to see if operations on these streams overlap in the way you expect them to. From my experience it is very easy to either miss a synchronization point (thus having data races between two streams) or having too many (e.g. by not double-buffering correctly), defeating the purpose of having multiple streams

Comment: I used the method of placing the final host function to be executed in the Streamqueue. When the stream completes all tasks sequentially on the device, I created a Callback function containing the host function to be executed.
Next, I placed the cudaHostLaunch function, which takes a Callback function as an argument, after the cudamemcpy (Device to Host). This makes it appear as if the CPU is accessing it after the device tasks are completed within the stream. Thanks a lot.